# How to run the input value with the function

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, dom

I have written this program in JavaScript and by inserting the values, the result is displayed in the console and it works properly
but I want to apply these functions by entering the value in the input,
I'm sorry if I did not explain correctly :)
please help me, thank you

HTML:
[html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygw99.png)

JavaScript:
[js image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM8bH.png)

Comment: Don't share image, Share your code snippet here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need link the function with the input, when input change

```
document.querySelector('#income').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    addIncome(userAccount, event.target.value);
});

document.querySelector('#outcome').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    addOutgo(userAccount, event.target.value);
});
```